# offset background image from top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to offset a background image that I am using for my contact section. I want the background to start something around 20px from the top of that section so that some of the content appears above the content.

This is my code for that section :

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="section-header wow fadeInUp" style="display: inline-block;">Contact Us</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                <!-- <div id="google-map" style="height:300px;" data-latitude="10.943816" data-longitude="76.934372"></div> -->
                <div id="map" style="height:300px;"></div>
                <script>

                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

My css for that section :

```
#contact {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url('../images/slider/bg1.jpg');
}
```

I'm actually trying to achieve the contact section like [here](http://logicsforest.com/multi-page-demo-4/)

But I am able to do only [this](https://v1chu.github.io/srs/#contact) so far.

Please help me achieve this.

Also the Google maps part does not seem to be responsive. Please let me know how I can make it resposive as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-position` to position the image

In your case you want to position it vertically so you need to use `background-position-y`

```css
#contact {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg');
  background-position-y: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="section-header wow fadeInUp" style="display: inline-block;">Contact Us</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
      <!-- <div id="google-map" style="height:300px;" data-latitude="10.943816" data-longitude="76.934372"></div> -->
      <div id="map" style="height:300px;"></div>
      <script>
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But when it is responsive, the offset height keeps varying. Is this the expected behavior or can I make it constant at all screen widths ?

Comment: @v1shnu If you use Pixels like i did, the offset will not vary... it remains at 50px for all screen sizes.. you can test the example i made and see :)